# Pass JSON from output for another query Ansible

Tags: json, linux, parsing, ansible, jmespath

Please help me figure out what I'm wrong with. I'm getting a JSON from Ansible and filtering it, after which I want to save the output and reuse it. But, unfortunately, I get an error that this attribute does not exist. Where did I go wrong?

playbook code:

```yaml
var:
  query_general: "body.results[].{display_name: display_name, subnets: subnets[]}"
```

```yaml
- name: parsing query
  set_fact:  
    myvar: "{{ results | json_query(query_general) }}"
  register: output

- name: qwe
  set_fact: 
    scndjson: "{{ output.myvar[].display_name }}"

- name: print
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ scndjson }}"
```

I tried the json_query second case as well, but that didn't work either.

in `register:output` i have:

```json
[
            {
                "display_name": "1test",
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "gateway_address": "0.0.0.0/25",
                        "network": "0.0.0.0/25"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "display_name": "test",
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "gateway_address": "0.0.0.1/25",
                        "network": "0.0.0.1/25"
                    }
                ]
            }
            ]
```

error:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable.

it can be: `output`, `display_name`, etc

UPD:
I corrected the yaml, there are no errors, but the data is not displayed.

```yaml
tasks:
   - name: 
     nsxt_rest:
       hostname: anyhost
       username: anyuser 
       password: anypass
       validate_certs: false
       method: get
       path: /policy/api/v1/infra/segments
     register: nsx_results

   - debug: 
         var: nsx_query_general
     vars: 
       nsx_query_general: "{{ nsx_results | json_query('body.results[].{display_name: display_name, subnets: subnets[]}') }}"
     register: output
  
   - debug:
        var: secondjson
     vars: 
       secondjson: "{{ output|json_query('[].display_name') }}"
```

Output from `nsx_query_general`:

```json
{
    "nsx_query_general": [
        {
            "display_name": "test",
            "subnets": [
                {
                    "gateway_address": "0.0.0.0/25",
                    "network": "0.0.0.0/25"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "display_name": "1test",
            "subnets": [
                {
                    "gateway_address": "0.0.0.1/25",
                    "network": "0.0.0.1/25"
                }
            ]
        }]}
```

Output from `secondjson`:

```json
{
    "secondjson": "",
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "changed": false
}
```

Comment: Awful idea to use the register of a `debug` in order to do something with it. Use a `set_fact` rather.

Comment: Same goes when you `set_fact`. use the fact that you just set, and not the result of the register for the `set_fact` task: `scndjson: "{{ myvar | json_query('[].display_name') }}"`, as provided by the actual answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, all methods give the same option - no data. Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the registered variable *output*

```yaml
output:
  - display_name: 1test
    subnets:
    - gateway_address: 0.0.0.0/25
      network: 0.0.0.0/25
  - display_name: test
    subnets:
    - gateway_address: 0.0.0.1/25
      network: 0.0.0.1/25
```

Either use *json_query*

```yaml
scndjson: "{{ output|json_query('[].display_name') }}"
```

, or *map* attribute

```yaml
scndjson: "{{ output|map(attribute='display_name')|list }}"
```

Both declarations create the list

```yaml
scndjson: [1test, test]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    output:
      - display_name: 1test
        subnets:
        - gateway_address: 0.0.0.0/25
          network: 0.0.0.0/25
      - display_name: test
        subnets:
        - gateway_address: 0.0.0.1/25
          network: 0.0.0.1/25
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: scndjson
      vars:
        scndjson: "{{ output|json_query('[].display_name') }}"
    - debug:
        var: scndjson
      vars:
        scndjson: "{{ output|map(attribute='display_name')|list }}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Vladimir.
I also tried using json_query, no errors, but no data =(
if I output register:output data via debug:msg , then I can see it. But if I add a query, I get: {
    "changed": false,
    "ansible_facts": {
        "parse": ""
    },
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
      What else can I add to the question to help sort out the problem? Maybe the difficulty is due to the fact that I'm trying to parse exactly the output of the previous request?

Comment: You're welcome. [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Post *results*. Post expected result. In *set_fact*, there is no reason to register a variable. Use the variable you set instead. Do not put code into the comment if you can put it into the question.